# Size with font deprecation

Tags: ios

I am using bar chart in that i am facing deprecation problem in "sizeWithFont" i dont know the replacement code..please help me out to overcome this issues

```
  for (NSString *label in _barLabels)
            {
                CGSize labelSize = [label sizeWithFont:self.xLabelFont];
                CGFloat labelHeightWithAngle = sin(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(_xLabelRotation)) * labelSize.width;

                if (labelSize.height > labelHeightWithAngle)
                {
                    _xLabelMaxHeight = MAX(_xLabelMaxHeight, labelSize.height);
                }
                else
                {
                    _xLabelMaxHeight = MAX(_xLabelMaxHeight, labelHeightWithAngle);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From now on, you should use

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithAttributes:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> * _Nullable)attrs;
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see `sizeWithFont` at Apple Developer site it is deprecated so we need to use `sizeWithAttributes`.

```
NSString *text = @" iOS 7.0";

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"7.0")) {
    // code here for iOS 5.0,6.0 and so on
    CGSize fontSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" 
                                                         size:12]];
} else {
    // code here for iOS 7.0
   CGSize fontSize = [text sizeWithAttributes: 
                            @{NSFontAttributeName: 
                              [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]}];
}
```

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Thank you.